# Orchestrate instances of a function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have 100 rows in an Azure table storage. But later I can add more rows or set "disabled" property on any row in the table.

I have an Azure function - "XProcessor". I would like to have an Azure function "HostFunction" which would start a new instance of the "XProcessor" for each row from the Azure table storage.

The "HostFunction" should be able to pass details of a table row to the instance of the "XProcessor" and the "HostFunction" needs to be executed every minute.

How do I achieve this? I am looking into the Azure Logic app but not sure yet how to orchestrate "XProcessor" with the details.

Comment: Have you checked `durable functions` ? Otherwise you can just move the code from the XProcessor function to another more generic fucntion  so you can invoke this directly from XProcessor and HostFunction functions. does that make sens for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to using a combination of "Durable Functions" techniques.

**Eternal Orchestration** - will allow you to enable your process to run, wait a set period of time after completion, and then run again.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations): Eternal orchestrations are orchestrator functions that never end. They are useful when you want to use Durable Functions for aggregators and any scenario that requires an infinite loop.

**Fan-in-fan-out** - will allow you to call a separate function per row.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-2-fan-outfan-in): Fan-out/fan-in refers to the pattern of executing multiple functions in parallel, and then waiting for all to finish. Often some aggregation work is done on results returned from the functions.

There is a bit of additional overhead getting going with durable functions but it gives you fine grained control over your execution. Keep in mind that state of objects is serialised in durable functions at every await call, so thousands of rows would potentially be an issue, but for the scenario you describe it will work well and I have had a lot of success with it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Durable functions is your go to option here. what you can do is 
1) Have a controller function called the orchestration function
2) Another child function which can be invoked multiple times by the orchestration
And in your orchestrate function, you wait till all the child instances give you the response back, hence you can get a fan-out- fan in scenario.

Have a look at following links
https://blog.mexia.com.au/tag/azure-durable-functions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview